# Runtime error while using exit_failure in a C program

Tags: c, standard-library

---

So I created a program where you have to enter a date dd/mm/yyyy and then you get date.day + 1 , but I wan't to verify that the date entered is valid, that is date.day between 1 and 31, month between 1 and 12 and year between 1 and 9999, and that day entered is less than the number of days of that month, if one of these fails return exit failure

```
     `// Program to determine tomorrow's date

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct date
    {
     int day;
     int month;
     int year;
    };

    int main(void)
    {
        struct date today, nextDay;
        bool isValidDate(struct date VarName);
        struct date dateUpdate(struct date today);


        printf("Enter today's date (dd mm yyyy): ");
        scanf("%i %i %i", &today.day, &today.month, &today.year);

        if (isValidDate(today) == false)
        {
            printf("Invalid date format. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        nextDay = dateUpdate(today);

        printf("Tomorrow's date is: %i/%i/%i \n", nextDay.day, 
        nextDay.month,             
        nextDay.year % 100);

        return 0;
    }
    // Function to update today's date to tomorrow's date
    struct date dateUpdate(struct date today)
    {
        struct date tomorrow;
        int numberOfDays(struct date VarName);

        if (today.day != numberOfDays(today)) // End of day
        {
            tomorrow.day = today.day + 1;
            tomorrow.month = today.month;
            tomorrow.year = today.year;
        }
        else if (today.month == 12)         // End of year
        {
            tomorrow.day = 1;
            tomorrow.month = 1;
            tomorrow.year = today.year + 1;
        }
        else                                // End of month
        {
            tomorrow.day = 1;
            tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
            tomorrow.year = today.year;
        }
        return tomorrow;
    }
    // Function to find the numbers of days in a month
    int numberOfDays(struct date VarName)
    {
        const int daysPerMonth[13] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
                                  31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
                                 };
        int days;
        bool isLeapYear(struct date VarName);
        bool isValidDate(struct date VarName);

        if (isLeapYear(VarName) == true && VarName.month == 2)
        {
            days = 29;
        }
        else
        {
            days = daysPerMonth[VarName.month];
        }

        return days;

    }
    // Function to determine if a year is a leap year
    bool isLeapYear(struct date VarName)
    {
        bool leapYearFlag;
        if ((VarName.year % 4 == 0 && VarName.year % 100 != 0) ||
            VarName.year % 400 == 0)
        {
            leapYearFlag = true; // It's a leap year
        }
        else
        {
            leapYearFlag = false; // Not a leap year
        }
        return leapYearFlag;
    }
    bool isValidDate(struct date VarName)
    {
        if ( (VarName.day < 1 && VarName.day > 31) || (VarName.day >         
         numberOfDays(VarName)) ) // Day format verifier
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (VarName.month < 1 && VarName.month > 12) 
                                                // Month format verifier      

        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (VarName.year < 1 && VarName.year > 9999)
                                                 // Year format verifier

        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
       }`
```

**TEST A**

Enter today's date (dd mm yyyy): 31 13 2018

**RESULT**

prog_8.4.c:78:16: runtime error: index 13 out of bounds for type 'const int [13]'
Invalid date format.

**TEST B**

Enter today's date (dd mm yyyy): 31 2 2018

**RESULT**

Invalid date format.

**TEST C**

Enter today's date (dd mm yyyy): 31 12 2018

**RESULT**

Tomorrow's date is: 1/1/19

if you notice, if there's a month that's greater than 13 I get a runtime error, which I don't want to get, I wan't to get the same message as test B where the day entered is greater than the days of that month, if I have my format verifier before the DateUpdate function why does the compiler runs the DateUpdate function, because I think that A error is related to this function, but if my error verifier worked correctly the program wouldn't run this function because it would terminate before it gets there, at least that's what I think, can you help me out here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem lies in here:

```
if ( (VarName.day < 1 && VarName.day > 31) || (VarName.day >         
     numberOfDays(VarName)) ) // Day format verifier
```

As you see in the below, there is no index for 13 in `const in daysPerMonth[13]`. You only have index from 0 to 12, and in function `bool isValidDate()`, you put the `Varname` without checking whether the index is between 1 to 12.

Checking the index before putting `Varname` inside `numberOfDays()` will fix your problem.

Comment: You are right, I was calling the numberOfDays() function without verifying that the VarName.month was between 1 and 12, to fix it I just re arranged the  isValidDate() function so the first if statement would be the one to verify that the month entered was valid